# How to set an environment variable when using gcloud ML engine?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, gcloud, google-cloud-ml

All,

(Environments: Windows 7, Python 3.6, Keras & tensorflow libs, gcloud ml engine)

I am running certain Keras ML model examples using gcloud ml engine as introduced [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/getting-started-training-prediction). Everything was fine but I just got various results among multiple runs although I was using the same training and validation data. My goal is to make reproductive training results from multiple runs.

I googled it for a while and found some solutions in this [Keras Q&A](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development) regarding making reproductive results. Basically they first suggested this:

> First, you need to set the PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable to 0 before the program starts (not within the program itself).

I know I could set the variables locally on my own machine, or I could set it when I deploy gcloud function as introduced [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var).

But, I just do not know how to set environment variables when I was using **gcloud ML engine** (on server side but NOT on local). So I cannot set "PYTHONHASHSEED=0" on the gcloud server when my model programs running there.

BTW, in general I know the randomness is a useful nature in the ML field but I am not very familiar about the topic of making reproductive results yet, so any thoughts regarding this topic are also welcome. Thanks!

Daqi

PS:
I have tried to setting the environment variables in running time below:

```
import os
os.environ["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "0" 
print(hash("keras"))
```

But it cannot make the effect that "setting the variables before the program starts". So by having this code, I still cannot get the same hash results from the multiple runs. On the other hand, on local, if I set "PYTHONHASHSEED=0" before running the code, I may get the same hash results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the Cloud ML Engine API provides a mechanism to set environment variables. However, you might be able to workaround this by writing a wrapper script (NB: UNTESTED CODE):

```
import os
import subprocess

env = os.environ.copy()
env["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = "0"

subprocess.check_call(['python', 'main.py'], env=env)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my late reply. I have implemented it as you said locally, it works. But when I run the same code using basic gcloud ml training, the internal real model program (model.py) that has been invoked from the wrapper (superprocess.py) always can NOT be found, as reported from gcloud log of the Job, like this "python: can't open file './model.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: But whatever, at least for this question, I think your answer is fairly good enough. I may open another ticket for the problem above. Thanks again~

Comment: can you try ['python', '-m', 'main']? Also, if you're using python3 be sure to use that instead (or use 'python-default').

Comment: Thanks! I am going to check it, using the '-m' parameter.

Comment: Hi, rhaertel80, eventually I have successfully run the model through the wrapper as you said. The tricky part is that, I made a copying process copy my model file from a gcloud gs location to the current folder during the running time before the invoking of the model, so that the model is able to be found when it is running on gcloud. BUT, I still got the different validation results even having the PYTHONHASHSEED being set to 0. Whatever, it is good for here now. We found a way setting environmental variables on gcloud side now:)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it orking