# "The replica master 0 ran out of disk." During Sklearn Fit in Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to use Google Cloud ML Engine to do an `sklearn LDA gridsearch` on 500 MB data (10000 rows x 26000 columns) to find what number of topics would be the best for my topic modeling project.

The maximum number of iterations for each CV fold was set to 100. 
After 47 iterations, the job would fail, citing the below error. I tried this using `BASIC` tier, `STANDARD` tier, and a `CUSTOM` tier with `masterType=complex_model_m`, and the same error happened every time.

I can't find much else on stackoverflow that talks about this problem, although I did come across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452871/solved-no-space-left-on-device-in-google-cloudml-basic-tier-what-is-the-disk), which seems to be related in some way. A solution was provided by the original asker:

```
Solved : This error was coming not because of Storage Space instead coming because of shared memory tmfs. The sklearn fit was consuming all the shared memory while training. Solution : setting JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER environment variable , to /tmp solved the problem.
```

I'm afraid I'm not entirely sure how to interpret or implement the solution.

Here are the three lines relevant to where the problem comes from:

```
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation(learning_method='batch', max_iter=100, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
gscv = GridSearchCV(lda, tuned_parameters, cv=3, verbose=10, n_jobs=1)
gscv.fit(data)
```

and I would call the job in the format:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \
        --package-path $TRAINER_PACKAGE_PATH \
        --module-name $MAIN_TRAINER_MODULE \
        --job-dir $JOB_DIR \
        --region $REGION \
        --config config.yaml
```

This is the absolutely abhorrent error message in the logs:

```
sklearn.externals.joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: """ Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/backend/queues.py", line 150, in _feed obj_ = dumps(obj, reducers=reducers) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 243, in dumps dump(obj, buf, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/backend/reduction.py", line 236, in dump _LokyPickler(file, reducers=reducers, protocol=protocol).dump(obj) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 284, in dump return Pickler.dump(self, obj) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 408, in dump self.save(obj) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 520, in save self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 623, in save_reduce save(state) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 810, in save_dict self._batch_setitems(obj.items()) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 836, in _batch_setitems save(v) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 520, in save self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 623, in save_reduce save(state) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 810, in save_dict self._batch_setitems(obj.items()) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 841, in _batch_setitems save(v) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 520, in save self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 623, in save_reduce save(state) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 810, in save_dict self._batch_setitems(obj.items()) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 836, in _batch_setitems save(v) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 770, in save_list self._batch_appends(obj) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 797, in _batch_appends save(tmp[0]) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 725, in save_tuple save(element) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 475, in save f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 740, in save_tuple save(element) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 481, in save rv = reduce(obj) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py", line 339, in __call__ for dumped_filename in dump(a, filename): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 502, in dump NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 408, in dump self.save(obj) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 289, in save wrapper.write_array(obj, self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C')) OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device """ The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals) File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/experiment_trainer/experiment.py", line 87, in <module> gscv.fit(data) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 722, in fit self._run_search(evaluate_candidates) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1191, in _run_search evaluate_candidates(ParameterGrid(self.param_grid)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 711, in evaluate_candidates cv.split(X, y, groups))) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 917, in __call__ if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 759, in dispatch_one_batch self._dispatch(tasks) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 716, in _dispatch job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async result = ImmediateResult(func) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 549, in __init__ self.results = batch() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__ for func, args, kwargs in self.items] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp> for func, args, kwargs in self.items] File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 526, in _fit_and_score estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py", line 570, in fit batch_update=True, parallel=parallel) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py", line 453, in _em_step parallel=parallel) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/online_lda.py", line 406, in _e_step for idx_slice in gen_even_slices(X.shape[0], n_jobs)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 930, in __call__ self.retrieve() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result return future.result(timeout=timeout) File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result return self.__get_result() File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357, in __get_result raise self._exception _pickle.PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers.
```

The most important of which I can only assume is:

`OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`

The message: `The replica master 0 ran out of disk.` was the official cause of the problem according to the console.

I can run this on my own desktop to 100 iterations no problem. Any insight on what's happening is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try setting that variable via a wrapper script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616287/how-to-set-an-environment-variable-when-using-gcloud-ml-engine JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER="/tmp" (NB: UNTESTED CODE)